# Can I do complex rollups or sums in Oracle View?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

At my job, I need to take some granular data collected in a twentieth of a mile and then roll it up to a tenth of a mile. This task is done with python scripts, but I was wondering if I can do it with a materialized view. Here is an example of what the data looks like it is simplest form, and what I would like the view to look like.

Simplest form:

| Route Number | Beginning Mile Post | Ending Mile Post | Route Length |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 0 | 0.02 | 105.6 |
| 001 | 0.02 | 0.04 | 105.6 |
| 001 | 0.04 | 0.06 | 105.6 |
| 001 | 0.06 | 0.08 | 105.6 |
| 001 | 0.08 | 0.10 | 105.6 |
| 001 | 0.10 | 0.12 | 105.6 |
| 001 | 0.12 | 0.14 | 105.6 |

This is what I want the view to produce:

| Route Number | Beginning Mile Post | Ending Mile Post | Route Length |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 0 | 0.1 | 528 |
| 001 | 0.1 | 0.14 | 211.2 |

I have tried using the rollup, sum, MOD, remainder, but not sure how to use them correctly.
I'm not even sure if this is possible through a view or not.

I will accept all suggestions and ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to use `TRUNC()` function while creating a view such as

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v_Route AS
SELECT Route_Number, 
       MIN(TRUNC(Beginning_Mile_Post,1)) AS Beginning_Mile_Post,
       MAX(Ending_Mile_Post) AS Ending_Mile_Post,
       SUM(Route_Length) AS Route_Length
  FROM t
 GROUP BY Route_Number, TRUNC(Beginning_Mile_Post,1)
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=e8cd8d3e576cf1eef108cceccb899141)</kbd>